# Excel VBA Graph Stretch Macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I wrote a previous macro to graph data on each of 300 sheets I have.

However, all of the graphs are too narrow to properly see the data:

```
Sub stretchtest()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(Charts(Charts.Count)).ScaleWidth 2, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
End Sub
```

This current code throws the error: "subscript out of range"

I want the macro to:
a) Take the most recently added chart and scale it to be twice as wide; OR 
b) Take all charts and make them all twice as wide.

Thank you!

Comment: The `Charts` collection refers to all **chart sheets** in a workbook, not the (embedded) chart(s) on a sheet, which would each be contained in a `ChartObject` - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/chart-object-excel). Do you have any other `Shapes` on these sheets?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
Sub stretchtest()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count).ScaleWidth 2, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
End Sub
```